# HttpClient web request issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, .net-core, httpclient

I have the below web request code. I am calling log in api getting a token back and adding the token to subsequent request. But this works only when I am using same http client for calling the second api. If create different http client and adding the token to request header and try to call the second api, it says unauthorised(401) access. Can anyone clarify why this is happening.

For some reason I want to make two HttpClient. Hence though one http client works but is not acceptable solution.

```
using (HttpClient client = SetupHttpClient())
{               
    StringContent encodedContent = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, MEDIA_TYPE_JSON);

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = Post(client, GetUri(logInUrl), encodedContent);
        responseArgs.IsConnectionOk = result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        responseArgs.ResponseContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        tokenValue = JsonHelper.GetValueFromJson(responseArgs.ResponseContent, "TokenValue");
        tokenName = JsonHelper.GetValueFromJson(responseArgs.ResponseContent, "TokenName");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokenName, tokenValue);

        //This works. Please notice we are reusing the same client variable. 
        HttpResponseMessage result1 = Post(client, GetUri("https://localhost/demo/abcapi"), null);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        responseArgs.IsConnectionOk = false;                    
    }
}

using (HttpClient client = SetupHttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokenName, tokenValue);

     //This does not work. Please notice the client variable is reinitialized.
    HttpResponseMessage result = Post(client, GetUri("https://localhost/demo/abcapi"), null);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why do you need two separate HttpClient instances? Disposing HttpClients are [really counter-productive](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: There is a differences you add client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); before client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokenName, tokenValue); at the second code.

Comment: I have requirement like that first I will hit the login URL will receive a token after that I need to call the actual URL but due to some reason I can not reuse existing HttpClient.